# Invoke a method in class without calling inside constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, constructor, frame

Using WPF/XAML to show pages on a MainWindows using Frame.

Navigating from page1 to page2 via button.

How can I call a method inside page2 class without invoking it inside the constructor?

Comment: Make it as static method

Answer (score 0):

Make it static, or if you're avoiding code in the constructor but need to get to other instance data, overload the constructor to have one include your code and one not

```
public MyPage()
{
    // code to avoid
}

public MyPage(bool otherData)
{
    // don't run the code in the default constructor
}
```

It depends on the reason you don't want to go through the constructor.